# Can't run an ova file

Tags: terminal, finder, virtualization, virtualbox

I download virtual box from http://www.modern.ie/en-US/virtualization-tools#downloads and extracted it. When I tried to run ova file, I couldn't.

```
$ sudo ./"IE11 - Win8.1.ova"
./IE11 - Win8.1.ova: ./IE11 - Win8.1.ova: cannot execute binary file

$ ./"IE11 - Win8.1.ova"
-bash: ./IE11 - Win8.1.ova: cannot execute binary file

$ ls -l "IE11 - Win8.1.ova"
-rwx------  1 alex  staff  3834711040 Mar 28 15:02 IE11 - Win8.1.ova
```

The same failure from Finder, it said

```
There is no application set to open the document “IE11 - Win8.1.ova”.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run .ova files from Terminal as they are not a binary file, hence the error. ova files are for VirtualBox, so you need VirtualBox to be able to open the file. Download VirtualBox from [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org).

Comment: isn't this - ova file - a Virtual Box itself?

Comment: @Alex [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) is an application, ova files are for VirtualBox. You need VirtualBox to be able to open the files in the same way you need Photoshop to open a psd.